# Dynamic where clause using Linq expression having join with multiple tables

Tags: linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

i have a linq query but in where clause is conditional. if eve.EventType is null then it will not include in where clause. How can we do with Linq lambda expression

```
var data= (from reg in product
                                join se in _order on reg.EventSessionId equals se.EventSessionId
                                join eve in Event on se.EventId equals eve.EventId
                                where eve.EventType == (EventType)eventType &&
                                ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eve.EventName) && eve.EventName.Contains(SearchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))                                    
                                select (new OrderHistory
                                {
                                    RegistrationId = reg.RegistrationId,
                                    EventName = eve.EventName,
                                    EventSesionName = se.EventSesionName,                                       
                                })).ToList();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.You should check null at first of your expression.

```
var data= (from reg in product
                            join se in _order on reg.EventSessionId equals se.EventSessionId
                            join eve in Event on se.EventId equals eve.EventId
                            where eve.EventType != null && eve.EventType == (EventType)eventType &&
                            ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eve.EventName) && eve.EventName.Contains(SearchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))                                    
                            select (new OrderHistory
                            {
                                RegistrationId = reg.RegistrationId,
                                EventName = eve.EventName,
                                EventSesionName = se.EventSesionName,                                       
                            })).ToList();
```